# Python: iterating in multiple levels

Tags: python, loops, iteration

```
-------------2000--------------
1        17824
2        20131125192004.9
3        690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
4    a       75601809 
4    a    DLC
4    b    eng
4    c    DLC
5    a    WA 750
-------------2001--------------
1        3224
2        20w125192004.9
3        690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
5    a    WA 120
-------------2002--------------
2        2013341524626245.9
3        484914s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
4    a       75601809 
4    a    eng
4    c    DLC
5    a    WA 345
```

I want to iterate through both the years and the fields under each year (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5). `a`, `b`, and other alphabet letters after some fields are subfields.

The lines with dashes in my code indicates the year of the entry. Each record group starts at ---year--- and ends at the line before ---year---.

Also, `fields` is a list:
`fields=["1", "2", "3,", "4", "5"]`.

I'm eventually trying to retrieve the values next to the fields for each entry/year. For example, if my current field is `1`, which is equivalent to `fields[0]`, I would iterate through all the years (2000, 2001, and 2002) to get the values for the field `1`. The output would be

```
17824
3224
(Blank space for Year 2002)
```

How can I iterate through the years (indicated by the dashes)? I can't seem to think of a code to generate the desired output.

Comment: Is this data saved in a file?

Comment: And what output you expect for the other fields, say for example '5' (field[4])?...is it going to be only 'a' or all what's next to it?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور: Yes, this data is saved as a text file. When selecting field[4] for example, the output would be what's next to the 'a'

Comment: @user112947...are u satisfied with the answers below or still expect others?

Answer (score 0):

You can first use regex to split your text then use `itertools.izip_longest` within a nested list comprehension to get your expected columns  :

```
>>> import re
>>> blocks=re.split(r'-+\d+-+',s)
>>> from itertools import izip_longest

>>> z=[list(izip_longest(*[k for k in sub if k])) for sub in izip_longest(*[[j.split() for j in i.split('\n')] for i in blocks])]
[[], [('1', '1', '2'), ('17824', '3224', '2013341524626245.9')], [('2', '2', '3'), ('20131125192004.9', '20w125192004.9', '484914s1969'), (None, None, 'dcu'), (None, None, '000'), (None, None, '0'), (None, None, 'eng')], [('3', '3', '4'), ('690714s1969', '690714s1969', 'a'), ('dcu', 'dcu', '75601809'), ('000', '000', None), ('0', '0', None), ('eng', 'eng', None)], [('4', '5', '4'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('75601809', 'WA', 'eng'), (None, '120', None)], [('4', '4'), ('a', 'c'), ('DLC', 'DLC')], [('4', '5'), ('b', 'a'), ('eng', 'WA'), (None, '345')], [('4',), ('c',), ('DLC',)], [('5',), ('a',), ('WA',), ('750',)], []]
```

each sub list represent a specific line in each block for example the first sub list is first lines in each block :

```
>>> z=[i for i in z if i] # remove the empty lists
>>> z[0]
[('1', '1', '2'), ('17824', '3224', '2013341524626245.9')]
>>> z[0][1]
('17824', '3224', '2013341524626245.9')
```

Comment: The desired output should be `('17824', '3224', ' ')` not `('17824', '3224', '2013341524626245.9')`

Answer (score 0):

So I'm writing a pretty involved answer that uses a helper function, but I think you'll find it pretty flexible.  It uses an iterutil type helper function that I wrote called groupby.  The groupby function accepts a key function to specify which group each item belongs to.  In your case the key function was a little fancy because it had to maintain state to know which year each element belonged to.  The code below is totally runnable.  Just copy and paste into a script and let me know what you think.

## EDIT

Turns out the groupby function is already implemented in the itertools module and I've been missing it forever.  I edited the code to use the itertools version

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io
import re
import itertools as it

data = '''-------------2000--------------
1        17824
2        20131125192004.9
3        690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
4    a       75601809 
4    a    DLC
4    b    eng
4    c    DLC
5    a    WA 750
-------------2001--------------
1        3224
2        20w125192004.9
3        690714s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
5    a    WA 120
-------------2002--------------
2        2013341524626245.9
3        484914s1969    dcu           000 0 eng
4    a       75601809 
4    a    eng
4    c    DLC
5    a    WA 345'''

def group_year():
    ''' 
    A stateful closure to group the year blobs together
    ''' 
    # Hack to update a variable from the closure
    g = [0]
    def closure(e):
        if re.findall(r'-----[0-9]{4}------', e): 
            g[0] += 1
        return g[0]
    return closure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = io.BytesIO(data)
    gy = group_year()
    for k,group in it.groupby(f, key=gy):
        # group is now an iter of lines for each year group in the data
        # Now you can iterate on each group like so:
        for line in group:
            rec = line.strip().split()
            if rec[0] == '1':
                print rec[1]
        # You could also use nested groupby's at this point to perform
        # further grouping on the different columns or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but because I am still a beginner, I don't really understand the code. Should I first copy and paste the code to see what happens?

Comment: Sorry!  Yes, please copy and paste into a script.  If you don't know how to make it executable and all that I can explain further.  Ignore the helper functions for now and focus on what's happening in the main loop.  Do you have a debugging environment set up?  I'd put a breakpoint in there to inspect what's happening.

Comment: Also, I'll edit my answer to return your desired result

Comment: Would the code differ drastically if it is a text file? For example, I would have to read the text file, possibly use `.readline()`

Comment: And yes, I have a debugging environment set up.

Comment: Almost nothing needs to change, no need for readline.  Python is smart with looping through lines of text files.  It should just look like: "f = open('<your_file>')" instead of the bytes io magic.  That's just a trick to make a string look like a file to code that expects files